# How to print the whole line that contains a specified byte offset in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-coreutils

I have such a example `input.txt` file:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Now I can easly grep for a word and get it's byte offset:

```
$ grep -ob incididunt /dev/null input.txt 
input.txt:80:incididunt
```

Sadly, the information about the line contents and the information about th  searched word gets lost. I only know the filename and the `80` byte offset. I want to print the whole line that contains that byte offset inside the file.

So ideally that would be to get a `script.sh` that with two parameters, a file name and a byte offset, outputs the searched line:

```
$ ./script.sh input.txt 80
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
```

Another examples:

For the file=input.txt and the byte offset=130 the output should be:

```
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
```

For the file=input.txt and any byte offset between 195 up until 253 the output should be:

```
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
```

For the file=input.txt and the byte offset=400 the output should be:

```
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

I have tried:

I can print from the byte offset up until the end of the line with gnu sed, however that misses the `eiusmod tempor` part. I can't think of any idea how to go "back" in the file, to fetch the part from the newline up until that byte offset.

```
$ sed -z 's/.\{80\}\([^\n]*\).*/\1\n/' input.txt 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
```

I can read character by character, remember last newline, and print from the last newline up until the next. That will not work with shells `read`, as it omits newlines. I think I can get it to work with using `dd`, but there's surely must be a simpler solution.

```
set -- inpux.txt 80
exec 10<"$1"
pos=0
lastnewlinepos=0
for ((i=0;i<"$2";++i)); do
        IFS= read -r -u 10 -N 1 c
        pos=$((pos+1))
        # this will not work..., read omits newlines
        if [ "$c" = $'\n' ]; then
                lastnewlinepost="$pos"
        fi
done
# as I know the last newline before the offset, it's ok to use this now
sed -z 's/.\{'"$lastnewlinepos"'\}\([^\n]*\).*/\1\n/' "$1"
```

How to print the whole line that "contains" the byte offset inside a file using bash and *nix specific tools?

Comment: Your example `input.txt` is not very clear about whether it is a very long line (wrapped on several lines to fit this page layout) or these are actually 3 distincts lines. In the case of a long line, the "80" offset makes sense, but not the output of your "ideal case".

Comment: No, they are several lines, that's why I used code formatting. I will try to  post more of lorem ipsum and more examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU awk, keep the number of bytes read so far in a variable, and when it reaches your *byte offset* print the current line and exit. E.g.:

```
$ awk -b '{ nb += length + 1 } nb >= 80 { print; exit }' file
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
```

The keyword `length` is a shorthand for `length($0)`, which returns the length of the current line in bytes (thanks to `-b`). We need to add 1 to it as awk strips off the line terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following, you can adjust input/output according to your needs, but this outputs you the actual offset of the word and the line containing the word:

```
#!/bin/bash
SEARCH_TERM="$1"
SEARCH_FILE="$2"
OFFSET_OF_WORD="`grep -ob $SEARCH_TERM $SEARCH_FILE | cut -d':' -f1`"

lastNewLinePos=0
lineNumber=0
for newLinePos in $(grep -b '$' $SEARCH_FILE | cut -d':' -f1)
do
    if (( $OFFSET_OF_WORD >= lastNewLinePos && $OFFSET_OF_WORD < $newLinePos )); then
        echo "Offset: $OFFSET_OF_WORD"
        echo "Line: `sed -n ${lineNumber}p $SEARCH_FILE`"
        break
    fi
    lastNewLinePos=$newLinePos
    let lineNumber++
done
```

EDIT: Tested with your given input and executed as

```
./getLineByOffset.sh incididunt input.txt
```

**Edit 2: If you only know the offset, not the actual search term**

```
#!/bin/bash
OFFSET_OF_WORD="$1"
SEARCH_FILE="$2"

lastNewLinePos=0
lineNumber=0
for newLinePos in $(grep -b '$' $SEARCH_FILE | cut -d':' -f1)
do
    if (( $OFFSET_OF_WORD >= lastNewLinePos && $OFFSET_OF_WORD < $newLinePos )); then
        echo "Offset: $OFFSET_OF_WORD"
        echo "Line: `sed -n ${lineNumber}p $SEARCH_FILE`"
        break
    fi
    lastNewLinePos=$newLinePos
    let lineNumber++
done
```

Comment: I do _not_ have the information about the word searched, I only know a byte offset and a filename. And what do you expect the `grep -ob '$' $SEARCH_FILE` to output? There are no `$` characters in the input file.

Comment: Then replace the `OFFSET_OF_WORD` variable by the offset you know, the `grep -ob $SEARCH_TERM $SEARCH_FILE ...` just searches the offset of the word. If you know it. Fine. A `grep -ob '$' $SEARCH_FILE` searches for line-endings in the file. The algorithm I use is "check if the given offset is WITHIN a line, i.e. the given offset is in between the last new line and the next new line"

Comment: This is nice! But the `grep -ob '$' input.txt` outputs nothing and exits with zero status. I have `grep (GNU grep) 3.3`.

Comment: That's strange, somehow the combination of `-ob` does not work with all `grep` versions. (Tested it myself with another version) But for this use-case the result is the same when using `-b` only. I edited my answer.